# Submitting a form with loaded form elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is generated using jQuery's `load()` function, I then attempt to submit the form using jQuery's `ajax()` function. It doesn't seem to work, and I guess it is because of the loaded content.

Here's what I'm working with:

I am using *three* pages for this certain operation,

- `Edit.php`
- `load-qstn-form.php`
- `edit-qstn.php`

Within `edit.php` this is the code that is relating to the issue,

The Element:

```
<form class="form-edit-qstn clr mrg-btm-med" method="post" action="./edit-qstn.php"></form>
```

The `.load()` which is from another *loaded element*:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trg-edit-qstn', function(event) {
    var that = $(this);
    var itemID = that.data("id");

    $('.form-edit-qstn').load('./load-qstn-form.php?id=' +itemID);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The `$.ajax` function:

```
$('.form-edit-qstn').submit(function(event) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        var form = $(this);
        var formid = form.find("input[name=formID]").val();
        var formname = form.find("input[name=formName]").val();
        var button = $('.form-edit-qstn button');

        $.ajax({
            method: form.attr("method"),
            action: form.attr("action"),
            data:   { formID: formid, formName: formname }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if(data != 0) {
                button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-success')
                    .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Success');
            } else {
                button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-danger')
                    .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i> Failure');
            };
            setInterval(function() {
                button
                    .removeClass('btn-success btn-danger')
                    .addClass('btn-default')
                    .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit');
            }, 5000);
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
          button
              .removeClass('btn-default')
              .addClass('btn-danger')
              .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i> Failure');
          setInterval(function() {
              button
                  .removeClass('btn-success btn-danger')
                  .addClass('btn-default')
                  .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit');
          }, 5000);
      })
  };
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is `load-qstn-form.php`:

```
<?php
  include("./config.php");

  $itemID = $_GET['id'];

  $getItem = $con->prepare("SELECT itemID,itemName FROM items WHERE itemID=?");
  $getItem->bind_param("i", $itemID);
  $getItem->execute();
  $getItem->store_result();
  if($getItem->num_rows > 0) {
    $getItem->bind_result($itemID,$itemName);
    while($getItem->fetch()) {
?>
<input name="formID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $itemID; ?>" required />
<table class="fixed full outline">
  <tr class="head">
    <td colspan="3"><p>Edit "<?php echo $itemName; ?>"</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Edit Question</p></td>
    <td><input name="formName" type="text" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>" autocomplete="off" required /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="btn-default"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit</button></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
    };
  } else {
?>
<p class="alert">No Item Found</p>
<?php
  };
  $getItem->close();
?>
```

Here is `edit-qstn.php`:

```
<?php
  include("./config.php");

  $formID = $_POST['formID'];
  $formName = $_POST['formName'];

  $updateQstn = $con->prepare("UPDATE items SET itemName=? WHERE itemID=?");
  $updateQstn->bind_param("si", $formName,$formID);
  if($updateQstn->execute()) {
?>
1
<?php
  } else {
?>
0
<?php
    print_r($updateQstn->error);
  };
  $updateQstn->close();
?>
```

I think the issue comes from the form elements being loaded, as this ajax code works from when I use it on a form that doesn't have loaded elements.

How do I bind the `input`s to the `document` ?

*note: some code is 4 spaces per tab, others 2 spaces per tab*

**Edit: It seems that the code falls short when it gets to `edit-qstn.php` as `$_POST` is passed correctly, but the database doesn't seem to update.**

Comment: Is the ajax not firing at all, or is it failing? Can you provide more information regarding the error?

Comment: @carl-k I get no response in the console or anything, I literally have no idea why it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing the issue... strangely enough `ajax method post` didn't work, so I attempted to change to `$.post` which seemed to work.

```
$('.form-edit-qstn').submit(function(event) {
  if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    var form = $(this);
    var formid = form.find("input[name=formID]").val();
    var formname = form.find("input[name=formName]").val();
    var button = $('.form-edit-qstn button');

    $.post(
      form.attr("action"),
      { formID: formid, formName: formname }
    )
    .done(function(data) {
      if(data != 0) {
        button
          .removeClass('btn-default')
          .addClass('btn-success')
          .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Success');
      } else {
        button
          .removeClass('btn-default')
          .addClass('btn-danger')
          .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i> Failure');
      };
      setInterval(function() {
        button
          .removeClass('btn-success btn-danger')
          .addClass('btn-default')
          .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit');
        formname = "";
      }, 5000);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      button
        .removeClass('btn-default')
        .addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i> Failure');
      setInterval(function() {
        button
          .removeClass('btn-success btn-danger')
          .addClass('btn-default')
          .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit');
        formname = "";
      }, 5000);
    })
  };
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code again, you are waiting for a `submit` event on your form element; however, there is no submit button in the retrieved code.

To keep your code as is, you can change the listener function:

`$('.form-edit-qstn').on('click', '.btn-default', function (e) {`

or change the type of the button to a submit:

`type='submit'`

`<button class="btn-default" type='submit'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i> Submit</button>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Even added **both** of these _fixes_ it still seems that the database isn't getting updated, even though there is no error and `$_POST` is being sent correctly. Note: Update page is `edit-qstn.php`

Comment: @user4985641, so you have confirmed that the AJAX request is now successfully being called and that they are being sen to the PHP script, but now they are not being saved in the database?